# Issue of ulong data type

Tags: c#-4.0

[image]

I am having above kind of method.So my question is When I passed **10.0** and **10.5** as parameters, How it returns **mask = 1048576** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you go through the loop once, with `i == 20`.

```
(ulong)1 << 20 == 1048576
```

---

To break it down - `10.0 * 2 == 20.0` and `10.5 * 2 == 21.0`.

Your for loop essentially is `for(var i = 20; i < 21; i++)`.

You then `or` the zeroed `mask` value with the result of `i << 20`, which is `1048576` and exit the loop.

Works as expected.

---

The right bit shift operator `<<` takes two arguments - the value to shift and by how much.

To understand it, you need to think in binary and how things are represented in binary.

For example, using 4 bits, you will see `1` represented as:

```
0001
```

If you left shift it two places:

```
1 << 2
```

You get:

```
0100
```

Which is `4` in decimal. The same applies to `<< 20` which moves all bits 20 positions to the left (discarding overflowing bits).

```
100000000000000000000 (binary) == 1048576 (decimal)
```

Comment: @Sampath - have you never walked through the code in your head? I don't understand where you think it shouldn't have?

Comment: Actually I need a explanation for when i<<20,how it becomes 1048576 ?

Comment: @Sampath - Rather vague question then ;) will add to answer.